# I'm trying to use "import" and I am getting discord module errors

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I know hardly anything about Javascript, but not too new to coding, so I'm sorry if there's a easy solution to this. I've been making a discord bot, and I've been trying to use `import random`, but whenever I do say that and run it I get back this error: `SyntaxError Cannot use import statement outside of module` on the line `import random`. So that's no issue, so went and added the line `"type": "module",` in the package.js file, but if I do *that* then this error comes up: `SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'const'` on the line right beneath it reading `const Discord = require('discord.js');`I don't know what I'm doing wrong and I would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Have you tried using require instead of import?

Comment: It says (if I try to use random.randint) that it doesn't exist

Comment: Currently you need to rename your `.js` to `.mjs` extension to enable import syntax.

Comment: @rawsome1234 `import random` is a python thing. It won't work in javascript

Comment: ah right this is javascript. I thought it was python because of the similar format up until I wrote this and doublechecked. How would I get a random number in java?

Comment: Found it, thank you very much